# Get django date from subtracted timezone now

Tags: python, django

I am subtracting django's model datetimefield from timezone.now() and its resturning 17 days ,20:33:09.233443 as output , how to get date format?

```
datetimefield = django_model.created_date
date_i_want = timezone.now() - datetimefield
print(date_i_want)
```

output:

```
17 days, 20:33:09.233443
```

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by date format? You are subtracting two dates from each other, so the result you get is the time between these dates. Are you expecting a different result?

Comment: yes like Y-m-d format please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.